# Is there a way with php ImageMagick to count number of pages into TIF image file without loading complete file?

Tags: php, imagemagick, tiff, imagick

let me describe the scenario.

**Environemnt**: RedHat linux 7.9 + ImageMagick* + pecl imagick + PHP script.

**Scope**: Into GUI application user must be allowed to see the single images from a multi-TIF file.

**File:** multi-tiff file are JPEG compressed.

**Problem:**
I have TIF file that contains N images, total size from few MB to 1/2GB and I need to access to them in two way much faster as possible:

1. [**KO**] Need **to count the total number of images** contained into TIF.

   `$img = new Imagick($filename); $img->getNumberImages();`

   With this way of access, the php class takes **quite long time** to load a TIF with ~2612 images,about 498M, like 15 seconds.(uncompressed tif is about 1.3G).
2. [**OK**] **Access to the #n image** into TIF to allow the user to see each single image.

   `$img = new Imagick($filename."[1]");$img->setImageFormat("jpeg");`
   `$thumbnail = $img->getImageBlob();`

   It is '**OK**' because the speed is high for the scope (always less than (and far from) 1 second)

** Both point 1/2 was tested with different imagick library version: 6.7.8-9, 6.9.10-68 Q16, 7.1.0 (Q16 HDRI) [pecl imagick 3.4 or 3.7] + GraphicsMagick-1.3.36, but there aren't a meaningful difference.

Is there an alternative to get the number of images into TIF without using time to initialize the full tif with **Imagick php class**?

Comment: The issue is probably that TIFF images are tagged and the multiple images contained in one can require you to download and seek around in the entire file to follow the chain of IFDs. I would try some other tools, just in the shell/Terminal to see if they are any faster... e.g. `tiffinfo`, `exiftool`, `libvips` and maybe **ImageMagick** with the `-ping` option to see if you can find something faster. Then maybe you can *"shell out"* to it if you find something good....

Comment: thank you for your suggestions. If I found any solution or alternatives i'll share it.

Answer (score 1):

I realize you asked for imagemagick, but [php-vips](https://github.com/libvips/php-vips) can do this pretty quickly. I tried:

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Jcupitt\Vips;

if(count($argv) != 4) {
    echo("usage: ./page.php input-image output-image page-number\n");
    exit(1);
}

// open and check the number of pages
$image = Vips\Image::newFromFile($argv[1]);
$n_pages = $image->get("n-pages");
echo("image $argv[1] has $n_pages pages\n" );

// grab a specific page
$page = Vips\Image::newFromFile($argv[1], ["page" => intval($argv[3])]);
echo("page $argv[3] is {$page->width} by {$page->height} pixels\n" );

// thumbnail the page to 500 pixels across and save as jpg
echo("thumbnailing ...\n");
// this is needed in current libvips to stop thrashing during thumbnail,
// it'll be unnecessary in 8.13+
$page = $page->sequential([
    "tile_height" => 128
]);
$thumb = $page->thumbnail_image(500);
$thumb->writeToFile($argv[2]);
echo("done\n");
```

I see:

```
$ ls -l ~/pics/sample/x.tif
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john 1471953608 Apr 14 09:31 /home/john/pics/sample/x.tif
$ time ./page.php ~/pics/sample/x.tif x.jpg 1234
image /home/john/pics/sample/x.tif has 2600 pages
page 1234 is 2900 by 2048 pixels
thumbnailing ...
done

real    0m0.296s
user    0m0.439s
sys 0m0.063s
```

So with a 1.4gb, 2600 page TIFF it can fetch and thumbnail a page in about 300ms.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Yes I am searching solution with imagick. But if not found, i'll have to evaluate alternatives also.